# Why can't I change my label text in tkinter (Python)?

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to set text for an existing label when myintro is initiated.

I'm getting this error :

> infoLabel.config(text = 'This is the intro!')   File
> "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1646, in configure
> return self.*configure('configure', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init**.py", line 1636, in _configure
> self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
> _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"

```
from tkinter import *

#Window properties
root = Tk()
root.title('CIT 144 Final, XXXX XXXX')
root.geometry('400x275')



#===============Functions==================
 
def myintro():
    infoLabel.config(text = 'This is the intro!')
      
def main():
    return

def buttonOneClick():
    return

    

#==============Window widgets definitions=================
infoLabel = Label(root, text = 'x')
inputBox = Entry(root, width = 18)
buttonOne = Button(root, text = '>>', width=5, command=buttonOneClick)


infoLabel.grid(column=0,row=0)
inputBox.grid(column=0,row=2)
buttonOne.grid(column=0,row=3)


root.mainloop()
myintro()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `myintro()` after `root.mainloop()`? `root.mainloop()` ends when the tkinter window is destroyed so the label no longer exists

Comment: ```python
def myintro():
    my_variable = infoLabel.config(text = 'This is the intro!')
    my_variable_text = my_variable.get()
```

now you can call your variable after mainloop.

Comment: @kirgizmustafa17 Now you are trying to call `<None>.get()`. Please note that `infoLabel.config(...)` doesn't return anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem when using tkinter's mainloop is that it will act as a "while" loop until the GUI's closed. If you invert these two lines:

```py
myintro()
root.mainloop()
```

the window label will display "This is the intro".

This is why I recommend using the "update" functions when using tkinter:

```py
from tkinter import *

#Window properties
root = Tk()
root.title('CIT 144 Final, XXXX XXXX')
root.geometry('400x275')

running = True

#===============Functions==================
 
def myintro():
    infoLabel.config(text = 'This is the intro!')
    root.update()
    root.update_idletasks()
      
def main():
    return

def buttonOneClick():
    return

    

#==============Window widgets definitions=================
infoLabel = Label(root, text = 'x')
inputBox = Entry(root, width = 18)
buttonOne = Button(root, text = '>>', width=5, command=myintro)


infoLabel.grid(column=0,row=0)
inputBox.grid(column=0,row=2)
buttonOne.grid(column=0,row=3)

while running:
    try:
        root.update()
        root.update_idletasks()
    except:
        break
```